# Retrieving latest 10 images per post from WordPress DB doesn't work. Possible fix?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I need to retrieve the latest 10 images for each post from the Posts table of a WordPress DB (MySQL 5.0) by using a custom MySql query, so I have written this one:

```sql
SELECT p.*, COUNT( p.post_parent ) AS counter
FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts AS p_temp
    ON p.post_parent = p_temp.post_parent AND
       p.post_date < p_temp.post_date
WHERE p.post_type = 'attachment' AND
      p.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' AND
      p.post_parent > 0 
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING counter <= 10
ORDER BY p.post_parent, p.post_date DESC
```

The problem is that I get a `counter` that doesn't start from 1 for each `post_parent` group, neither is sequential. So the result isn't reliable.

Some sample data the test database returns me:

```
ID    post_date             post_parent   post_type    counter
---------------------------------------------------------------
502   2020-03-02 17:42:03   463           attachment   2
474   2020-01-28 18:41:55   463           attachment   5
933   2020-10-26 09:28:54   497           attachment   1
932   2020-10-26 09:28:34   497           attachment   2
500   2020-03-02 17:29:08   497           attachment   6
499   2020-03-02 17:28:55   497           attachment   7
498   2020-03-02 17:28:43   497           attachment   8
```

How could I fix the query so that it does return max 10 results (images) for each value of `post_parent` (the ID of the post to which images are attached)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky, particularly because some posts may not have ten rows.  So, the basic idea is similar to GMBs answer, but while taking into account that there are not 9 rows (and using the correct columns):

```
select p.*
from wp_posts p
where p.post_type = 'attachment' and
      p.post_mime_type like 'image/%' and
      p.post_parent > 0 and
      p.post_date >= coalesce( (select p2.post_date
                                from wp_posts p2
                                where p2.post_type = 'attachment' and
                                      p2.post_mime_type like 'image/%' and
                                      p2.post_parent > 0
                                order by p2.post_date desc
                                limit 9, 1
                               ), p.post_date
                             );
```

EDIT:

If you want this *per* `post_parent` use a correlation clause:

```
      p.post_date >= coalesce( (select p2.post_date
                                from wp_posts p2
                                where p2.post_type = 'attachment' and
                                      p2.post_mime_type like 'image/%' and
                                      p2.post_parent = p.post_parent
                                order by p2.post_date desc
                                limit 9, 1
                               ), p.post_date
                             );
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem with the query you have suggested is that it returns at max a total of 10 results, no matter the value of `post_parent`, when I would like to retrieve max 10 results for each value of `post_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am following correctly, you want 10 rows per `post_parent`, where the ordering is defined by column `counter`. Here is one approach using a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select p.*
from wp_posts p
where 
    p.post_type = 'attachment' and p.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' and p.post_parent > 0
    and p.counter <= (
        select p.counter
        from wp_posts p1
        where p1.post_type = 'attachment' and p1.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' and p1.post_parent = p.post_parent
        order by p1.counter
        limit 9, 1
    )
```

This gives you the "first" 10 rows per `post_parent`. If you want the latest 10, then you would change `<=` to `>=`, and `order by p1.counter limit 9, 1` with `order by p1.counter desc limit 9, 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Probably I misled you because counter isn't a column of the `wp_posts` table but the alias for `COUNT( p.post_parent )`. The idea was to use `counter` as a limiter for the number of rows to retrieve for each group of `post_parent`.